# Exploit mitigation/security hardening for Yocto images

Tags: security, yocto, openembedded

What does Yocto/OE provide to enable existing exploit mitigation techniques available in the kernel, toolchain and userspace? Things like ASLR, stack protector, secure user copy, disabling ptrace, ...

Do I have to configure these things by hand or is there something in Yocto that will help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An documentation entry point addressing my questions can be found here: 
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#making-images-more-secure

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#security-flags describes how to compile programs with more secure compiler flags.

The flags enable the stack protector, FORTIFY_SOURCE, position independent code (for ASLR), string format checks and readonly relocations. It also maintains a blacklist of packages known not to build with these options. These are compiled with less stringent flags. These flags affect the user space.

Yocto does not offer a central switch to enable mitigations/hardening in the kernel itself. This has to be done manually via kernel config fragments.

A Yocto layer containing various means and tools to harden an image can be found here:
https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-security/tree/README

Answer (score 0):

inside the meta-security/recipes-security there are some tools like checksec (checking the elf, shared libraries etc. for support the aslr, relro, nx, pie). You can check the directory and can use the tools for thing like this.